# MvcContrib.Castle Meduim Trust & Signed Assemblies

Tags: .net, medium-trust

I have a class library which references MvcContrib.Castle. My Assembly is signed, but will not compile

error

`Error  129 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'MvcContrib.Castle' does not have a strong name`

I have tried added to the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
using System.Security;
[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]
```

the issue persists.

I have tried the following too: http://paulwideman.com/softwareartist/tag/medium-trust/

Anyone know what todo?

if it helps im using .net 4

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can sing MvcContrib dlls without rebuilding them, for example with this tool: http://signer.codeplex.com/